# Не проходит тест простая программа на CodeForces

Tags: python

Код не проходит 4 тест в задаче на Кодефорс

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/550/A

Пробовал различные вариации решений, например как ниже

```
if 'BAB' in a or 'ABA' in a:
    print('NO')
elif 'AB' in a and 'BA' in a:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Что требуется в задаче - я понял, нужен именно код на пайтоне без регулярных выражений и который пройдет 4 тест.
**Или если знаете что в 4 тесте - скажите**

Comment: Вообще выглядит правильно, не представляю, какой должен быть вариант, чтобы такая проверка не сработала. А что пишет, какой результат проверки? Может там по скорости не проходит или что-то такое, тут можно чуть оптимизировать попробовать эти проверки. И вообще по-другому проверять. В худшем случае у вас 4 раза вся строка проверится, может в это упирается.

Comment: `if 'BAB' in a or 'ABA' in a:
    print('NO')` - это ж не верно. Например, строка `ABABA` вполне себе содержит две не пересекающиеся подстроки `AB` и `BA`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет, это маловероятно. Плюс код довольно таки быстро выполняется и другие тесты также проходит хорошо (первые 3 то есть)

По результату - просто пишет, что "неправильный ответ на 4 тесте"

Comment: @GrAnd А вот это хорошая идея, да

Comment: @GrAnd  Кстати да, видимо все же суть задачи не понял, спасибо :3

Comment: Я вижу такой алгоритм: при помощи `find()` найти индексы подстрок и проверить их на -1 и на то, что их разница по модулю больше 1.

Comment: Решение то я придумал, но думаю автор вопроса лучше сам пускай теперь решит, когда понятно, в чём дело )